# CartThrob VAT issue

Tags: cartthrob, tax

I'm building an order process to order a specific item, separate from the rest of the site's CT Checkout process.

I've turned VAT off for the specific item but VAT is being added to the overall order.

**How do I turn off VAT for a specific order?**

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this, added `tax_exempt="yes" shipping_exempt="yes"` to the `{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}` tag.